# Sci-Fi/Romance novel from 1990s (?) with girl who moves in with her bachelor uncle

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel when I was a teenager, and my sister and I can't remember the title or author.

The only things I remember about the book are that I believe it was a fantasy/sci-fi/paranormal romance YA novel in the early to mid 90s, and that it was about a girl who moved in with her bachelor uncle (in Scotland, I think).

She was attending or working a Renaissance Fair, she listened to REM's "Losing My Religion" and she had multi-colored hair. One of her love interests was a guy named Ian, who worked for her uncle, and he was her protector. Oh and he had a sword.

There may have been some sort of cult-type bad guys that were after her too.

Comment: Please edit the title so it contains more information about your book. I'll do it now so you have an example...

Comment: Do you remember anything about what parts were supernatural?